# Using $dirty in angularjs in order to check whenever a form is being edited

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, form-editing

I was trying to check whenever my form is being edited by writing some fields of it. I read $dirty should work for that task but I can't figure out what I'm missing here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form name = "myForm" novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
  </form>
  <p> is Form dirty? {{isDirty}}<p>
  <p>form = {{user }}</p>
  <p>master = {{master}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"};
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
    $scope.isDirty = $scope.myForm.$dirty;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make the flag isDirty to true whenever the user modifies the form. Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that an edit and undo of text on the form will result in `$dirty` being true even though the current and former values are the same. If you want to determine whether there are unsaved changes then you should compare the original to the current.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are missing `name` attributes in your form fields which are not enabling form validation for those field. You need to add unique name for each field so that it will get add those field in `myForm` object

**Markup**

```
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
  </form>
```

Also you are accessing `myForm` object which is nothing but form object, I won't be available until DOM get rendered, `$scope.myForm` will be simply undefined at the time of controller initilization, If you really want to access `$scope.myForm` from controller then you need to put that code in `$timeout` that will run `$timeout` function code in next digest cycle.

```
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.isDirty = $scope.myForm.$dirty;
  });
```

**Update**

There is no need to maintain a **separate** `isDirty` flag (this would require to *change* the separate `isDirty` flag to reflect any changes in `myForm.$dirty` flag.) Instead I suggest you use `$scope.myForm.$dirty` **directly** as a flag. So use the expression `myForm.$dirty`, and this flag will change as form gets dirty.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OYpuXKgGz7GK915mQ66Q?p=preview)

Comment: I just tried to modify as you suggested adding the name attributes but its not working. I keep getting the same error: --> TypeError: Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined

Comment: thanks for the Plunkr but , I have just tried it and can only see the false value of the isDirty variable , I wish it becomes true as soon as the user starts to modify some field of the form, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @DarkAngeL  your html would be simply `<p> is Form dirty? {{myForm.$dirty}}<p>` no need of extra variable

Comment: @PankajParkar This is nice, but how can I use javascrcipt/angular to always watch the value of  `myForm.$dirty` in your Plunkr? In your Plunkr I just edited this `      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.isDirty = $scope.myForm.$dirty;
        alert($scope.isDirty);
      });`  but works only the first time the page loads. When I edit the form I get nothing. Thanks

Comment: Can also check $dirty on the individual "form controls"; i.e. an input added of the form. `<p> individual form control dirty: {{ myForm.firstName.$dirty }} </p>`