# Check if form is touched

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

In angular I want to do this

```
<script>
  //inside the controller
  $scope.myForm.$dirty{
    //hide some divs etc.
  }
</script>
```

How can I do this only in JavaScript, without putting any of the validation in my HTML?

**update**

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" ng-submit="login()" novalidate>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-click="hideInvalidUsername()" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>

</form>
```

and in my controller

```
  app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService' ,
  function ($scope, localStorageService ) {  

if($scope.loginform.$dirty) { alert("yo"); }
```

Comment: write it in a .js file, and include that in your html?

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't quite clear, but I guess you'd like to do this:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="message" ng-show="myForm.$dirty">the form is dirty</span>
</form>
```

A form will automatically bind to your scope in a variable with the `name` attribute

Comment: @Martjin Let me explain. I dont wont to write code in HTML like ` ng-show="myForm.$dirty"`. I want to check if the form is touched using javascript and angular in my controller. Something like `$scope.myForm.$dirty{` . Is this possible?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, you could just do `if($scope.myForm.$dirty) { doSomething(); }`

Comment: Use watcher expression on myForm.$dirty

Comment: @MartijnWelker Thanks but I get `Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined`.  `myForm` is the `name` of the form, right?

Comment: @slevin Yes, if you add your code to a plunkr ill have a look

Comment: @MartijnWelker Check the original post , I updated it, adding the schema of the code. Thanks

Comment: @MartijnWelker There is a good explanation in Pankaj Parkar answer here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096083/using-dirty-in-angularjs-in-order-to-check-whenever-a-form-is-being-edited` . But it does not watches the value of `$dirty` all the time. Still working on it. So frustrated

Comment: @slevin why don't you place a watcher on it, like this: `$scope.$watch('myForm.$dirty', function(n) {if(n) {alert ('dirty'); }});`

Comment: @MartijnWelker I got what i was looking for from your comment, My question is why do we use if(n) ?  Can you explain.